# Not Selecting repeat data SQL

Tags: php, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
 Make  | Model
 --------------
 Ford  | Bronco
 Ford  | Taurus
 Honda | Accord 
 Ford  | Thunderbird
 Saab  | 900
```

I need an SQL statement to output only `Ford`, `Honda` and `Saab` from the column `Make`.

Comment: `select distinct Make from yourtable`.

Comment: Does anyone else find it ridiculous that we had a combined 100k+ rep in 4 users answering a question that is easily anwered by any entry-level SQL tutorial online?

Comment: @JNK Well I think you persuaded him :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Make 
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY Make;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select distinct Make from table_name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Make
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Make
FROM MyTable
```

That's it.